# Inserting data in a tabel with foreign keys

Tags: php, sql, database

I have made a database for a school project relations, It's supposed to a RPG where a user can create characters and give them stats and a picture.

I have chosen to keep the picture in a separate table, so that when they update something on the character, they don't have to update the picture.

I thought when i inserted data when making a character that you could the foreign keys would just be auto incremented, because they linking to the other tables. But now i'm not sure how to do it, of if I've made the database wrong. 
[Database View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3t6u.png)

```
 $sqlcharacter = ("INSERT INTO characters(Cname, Clast, Crace, house, 
 location, Bgstory, user_id, img_id, stats_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
 ?, ?)");
 $stmtChar = $conn->prepare($sqlcharacter);
 $stmtChar->bind_param('ssssssiii', $Cname, $Clast, $Crace, $house, 
 $location, $bgstory, $user_id, $img_id, $stats_id);
 $stmtChar->execute();

 $sqlstats = ("INSERT INTO cstats(Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, 
 Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma, Aligment) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $stmtstats = $conn->prepare($sqlstats);
 $stmtstats->bind_param("iiiiiis", $strength, $dexterity, $constitution, 
 $intelligence, $wisdom, $charisma, $aligment);
 $stmtstats->execute();

 $sqlimg = ("INSERT INTO cimages(image) VALUES(?)");
 $stmtimg = $conn->prepare($sqlimg);
 $stmtimg->bind_param('s', $images);
 $stmtimg->execute();
```

Comment: The table that stores the image, should have a primary id. It is this, that you get from the image table, after you store thee image, then you store it in the other table as the foreign key!

Comment: Or you could add c_id to image table as foreign key in image table, and retrieve the image based on this!

Comment: Auto incrementing a foreign key would not work, because there is no way for it to know what it is actually pointing to. You have to make an extra db call, to retrieve the id, so you can use it as a foreign key!